# How does SOA service composition work at the code level?

Tags: web-services, soa

Service composition is a fundamental part of SOA. All of the
capabilities offered by a service inventory are expected to utilize
other services within that inventory, where necessary, in order to
build the task that they are accomplishing from smaller component
parts. This is all from an architectural level, though: how does this
composition happen at the implementation level?

Consider this situation. I have a "task service" which involves
posting a `/process-request` resource that will manage additional
resources involved in asynchronously processing a large file to
generate the "real" resource.  Let's call the eventual "real" resource
a PartsInventory.  So, you provide a URL and a name for the
PartsInventory to the `/process-request` service, which then creates
a PartsInventory "placeholder" and kicks off the asynchronous ETL
involved in converting the massive csv file at your URL into a real
PartsInventory.  If this asynchronous job fails, it will remove the
placeholder and queries to the `/process-request` service will
reflect the failure.  If it succeeds, it will remove the placeholder
status and queries to the `/process-request` service will instead
redirect you to the PartsInventory resource.

Now, how does the implementation of the interaction between
`/process-request` and the PartsInventory *look*, from a code
standpoint?  Am I POSTing requests to a published `/parts-inventory`
service, or am I calling ORM objects to create the placeholder?  If
the former, I am abiding by the published contract and am behaving as
a consumer of my own services, which seems to fit the composability
principle--but it feels really awkward to interact this way from
within the same codebase. On the other hand, the latter presumes that
the `/process-request` handler is going to know about how to create
a PartsInventory placeholder on its own, which feels awkward in
itself. The third option would be to create a specialized static
factory method on the PartsInventory object, called something along
the lines of `PartsInventory.create_placeholder()`, so that the
`/process-request` code is at least ignorant of the constructor
dependencies of a PartsInventory object. This does still separate
creation into two locations, though.

Have you encountered this? Is there a canonical "right answer" to this
question?

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate between service endpoints (in your case urls exposed by the various services) and services. Services are basically components with, what should be, well defined boundaries that expose one or more endpoints where they deliver contracts (made of messages).

Calls made within the service don't have to go through service interface calls that cross service boundaries do have to go through service interface.

The question in your case is are process-request and PartsInventory different aspects of the same service or not. I can't understand from the details in your service if they are or aren't but if they really make sense as different services you should go through the service interface.